# How to handle Pop-up in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, popup, popupwindow

I want to handle sign-in part in rediff.com, but the below code doesn't work for that:

```
driver.get("http://www.rediff.com/");
WebElement sign = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[3]/div[3]/span[4]/span/a"));
sign.click();
String myWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().window(myWindowHandle);
WebElement email_id= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='signin_info']/a[1]"));
email_id.sendKeys("hi");
```

If `myWindowHandle` is not the correct string, then let me know how to get the pop-up Window name, because I can't find the name of the pop-up window.

Comment: Take the list of windows by using driver.getWindowHandles().

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To switch to a popup window, you need to use `getWindowHandles()` and iterate through them.

In your code you are using `getWindowHandle()` which will give you the parent window itself.

```
String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
String subWindowHandler = null;

Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
}
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window

// Now you are in the popup window, perform necessary actions here

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);  // switch back to parent window
```

Comment: But i just need to handle only one window than i think so no meaning to use iterator ...do u have another way . i just need to write email address and password in sign in form of rediff.com .pls helm me in this .

Comment: The above code will handle that. Once you switch to sub window which is your popup. Pick the webelements and fill in your email id, password and submit. Then switch back to your parent window.

Comment: Tried but code is not working on link : rediff.com -> click on sign in link and try to signed in

Comment: @Johnp2: please don't hijack the answer

Answer (score 11):

I found the solution for the above program, which had the goal of signing in to http://rediff.com

```
public class Handle_popupNAlert
{
    public static void main(String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(); 
        driver.get("http://www.rediff.com/");
        WebElement sign = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[3]/div[3]/span[4]/span/a"));
        sign.click();

        Set<String> windowId = driver.getWindowHandles();    // get  window id of current window
        Iterator<String> itererator = windowId.iterator();   

        String mainWinID = itererator.next();
        String  newAdwinID = itererator.next();

        driver.switchTo().window(newAdwinID);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.close();

        driver.switchTo().window(mainWinID);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        WebElement email_id= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='c_uname']"));
        email_id.sendKeys("hi");
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can handle popup window or alert box:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

You can also decline the alert box:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert().dismiss();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below code inside your code when you get any web browser pop-up alert message box.

```
// Accepts (Click on OK) Chrome Alert Browser for RESET button.

Alert alertOK = driver.switchTo().alert();
alertOK.accept();



//Rejects (Click on Cancel) Chrome Browser Alert for RESET button.

Alert alertCancel = driver.switchTo().alert();
alertCancel.dismiss();
```

Comment: You can use the above code inside your code when you get any web browser pop up alert message box.

Answer (score 2):

Do not make the situation complex. Use `ID` if they are available.

```
driver.get("http://www.rediff.com");
WebElement sign = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in"));
sign.click();
WebElement email_id= driver.findElement(By.id("c_uname"));
email_id.sendKeys("hi");
```

Comment: I can''t directly use email_id field as its in pop up window ..pls visit rediff.com as i want to write email address and password in sign in form of rediff.com. link: http://www.rediff.com/

Comment: which browser are you using? Because i am not seeing any pop up window after clicking on sign-in. it is just another modal window (inside main window). i am using firefox23.

Comment: yeh i need to access that and signed in

Comment: what is error you are getting while clicking on `sign-in` link? Any permission error?

Comment: didn't get any error but not able to handle email address field

Comment: Are you getting `no such element` exception ?

Answer (score 0):

When the toastr message poped up on the screen of firefox. the below tag was displayed in fire bug.

```
<div class="toast-message">Invalid Credentials, Please check Password</div>.
```

I took the screenshot at that time.
And did the below changes in selenium java code.

```
String alertText = "";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("toast-message")));
WebElement toast1 = driver.findElement(By.className("toast-message"));  
alertText = toast1.getText();
System.out.println( alertText);
```

And my issue of toastr popup got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
String subWindowHandler = null;

Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();

subWindowHandler = iterator.next();

driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window

// Now you are in the popup window, perform necessary actions here

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);  // switch back to parent window
```

Answer (score 0):

## It isn't Java, but if the comparison helps, here is a simple Python solution in Chrome that handles the question in a single line.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# Save a list of all open window handles
window_handles = driver.window_handles

# Open new window with click() action - modify as needed.
get_element(driver, By.XPATH, "//input[@title]").click()

# Get and switch to the pop-up window
new_popup_window = list(set(driver.window_handles) - set(window_handles))[0]
driver.switch_to.window(new_popup_window)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
       //get the main handle and remove it
       //whatever remains is the child pop up window handle

       String mainHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
       Set<String> allHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
       Iterator<String> iter = allHandles.iterator();
       allHandles.remove(mainHandle);
       String childHandle=iter.next();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void Test(){

     WebElement sign = fc.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-scroll']/a"));
        sign.click();
        WebElement LoginAsGuest=fc.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='guest-login-option']"));
        LoginAsGuest.click();
        WebElement email_id= fc.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='guestemail']"));
        email_id.sendKeys("ankushdeoladore@gmail.com");
        WebElement ContinueButton=fc.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='contibutton']"));
        ContinueButton.click();

}
```