# How to check if a popup window is open or not using Selenium WebDriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to check whether the popup window I want to open is opened or not.

I have checked some question answers like

> [How would you check if a popup window exists using selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911681/how-would-you-check-if-a-popup-window-exists-using-selenium-webdriver)

But, nothings helped to solve the problem.

Here, first I open the login window by clicking the login button.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='login_btn']")).click(); // Click Login Button
```

[image: login]

I even tried `getPageSource()` but, it seems not working.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: probably its not a pop-up; it is just a frmae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String mwh=driver.getWindowHandle();
```

Now try to open the popup window by performing some action:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();

Set s=driver.getWindowHandles(); //this method will gives you the handles of all opened windows

Iterator ite=s.iterator();

while(ite.hasNext())
{
    String popupHandle=ite.next().toString();
    if(!popupHandle.contains(mwh))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
        /**/here you can perform operation in pop-up window**
        //After finished your operation in pop-up just select the main window again
        driver.switchTo().window(mwh);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's a native, browser alert (= a popup) you can do the following:

```
try{
    driver.switchTo().alert();
    // If it reaches here, it found a popup
} catch(NoALertPresentException e){}
```

What it looks like you're actually dealing with is an iframe which you can do the following after getting the attribute value of the "iframe" attribute:

```
driver.switchTo.frame("ValueOfIframe");
// Treat as normal webpage. Now in iframe scope
driver.switchTo.defaultContent(); // To return back to normal page scope
```