# selenium webdriver to identify the google play store popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I was trying to identify the element in the google play store using firebug the element was identified by the firebug successfully but when I execute the selenium code it throws Invalid selector exception.

```
1. Login to playstore with the gmail account.
2. In the search box, type whatsapp and click on install button
3. It opens popup, I wanted to click on dropdown values and then click on install or just click on cancel button

For the cancel button, I wrote the following code:
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='purchase-cancel-button']")).click();
which is not working.
```

[image]

Comment: Is whatsApp a Google App too now?

Comment: Why bother using an XPath when an id is available? Unless you are specifically looking for a child element of another element I would use "//" instead of ".//".

Comment: Have you used `getWindowHandles()` to work with the pop-up window? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403949/how-to-handle-pop-up-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java for example

Answer (score 0):

Try with below cssSelectors

```
By.cssSelector("button[id='purchase-cancel-button']");
Or
By.cssSelector("div.modal-dialog button[id='purchase-cancel-button']");
```

Answer (score 0):

This item is currently invisible so you have to make a delay for a couple of seconds, f.e.

`

```
      (driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                '//*[@id="body-content"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/span/span/button')).click()

      time.sleep(4)

      (driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="purchase-ok-button"]')).click()
```

`