# Selenium RemoteWebDriver button Click method exception timed out even though the button is clicked

Tags: c#, selenium, exception, timeout, remotewebdriver

I have the following code to click on a button. When I debug it, it goes past the Click() line, and the button is clicked (I can see a new window popping up as expected). However, it then just sits there for a minute, then returns with a time out exception. It doesn't go to the next line of code.

Also, this seems to happen only for this button where a new pop-up window is launched after it's clicked. Other buttons on the page seem to be fine.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

```
var button = DriverFactory.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("ctl07_Customers_OCS_ListForms_btnAddCustomer"));
button.Click(); // A new pop-up window is opened
// Next line of code - It times out before it can hit the following line
DriverFactory.Instance.SwitchTo().Window(DriverFactory.Instance.WindowHandles.Last());
```

Exception Details:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2146233088
>     Message=The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7055/hub/session/5e7fc81a-ed31-4310-9419-f1e5cc0d1b35/element/%7B96a49e56-d619-4765-b0a7-222f69da23bf%7D/click timed out after 60 seconds.
>     Source=WebDriver
>     StackTrace:
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
>          at OCSPortalFramework.Pages.BankPortal.ListFormsPage.ClickAddCustomer() in C:\Src\EPSQA\Regression_Portals\OCSPortal\OCSPortalFramework\Pages\BankPortal\ListFormsPage.cs:line 25
>          at OCSPortalTests.OCS_146710_Add_Customer.OCS_146710_Add_Customer_Test() in C:\Src\EPSQA\Regression_Portals\OCSPortal\OCSPortalTests\OCS_146710_Add_Customer.cs:line 52
>     InnerException: 
>          HResult=-2146233079
>          Message=The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
>          Source=System
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>               at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
>          InnerException:

Answer (score 1):

Work around for this is:

```
try {
button.click();
thread.sleep(300);
}
catch(Exception e) {
//System.out.println("" +e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but it didn't matter since the exception occurs right AFTER the Click() method, so it doesn't get to to the next line. I updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: try this solution specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403949/how-to-handle-pop-up-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: I added the following line (DriverFactory.Instance.SwitchTo().Window(DriverFactory.Instance.WindowHandles.Last());) after the Click method (my C# version of the Java post), but again it didn't matter since the Click() method returns the exception before the code to switch window is hit.

Comment: Try giving sleep time before click(); i mean `thread.sleep(250);` then do `button.click()`

Comment: Yes I did that before. Didn't help :(.

Comment: just add try catch block and it works: for example 

try
            {
                WebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.Id("lookupimg"));
                ele.Click();
                Thread.Sleep(300);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                //Console.WriteLine(e);

            }

and give sleep and it works perfectly
(Source:https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5071)

Comment: Yes that Try Catch works (even though I don't quite understand how that fixes it since the Catch block wasn't even hit)!!! Thanks so much for your help. Can I please send you a thank you gift? :)

Comment: Do you mind editing (or create a new response) so that I can mark it as Answered? Thank you so much again!