# How to get driver when pop up appears - Selenium

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

I am finding difficulties to get the driver when popup appears. when I click a button, then it will open another browser window. can someone give me the tips how to get the driver on the popup browser? thank you [image: this is the popup browser window]

Comment: Please show the code you are using and explain the error or issue you are facing.

Comment: Resolved: You see the same question and answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403949/how-to-handle-pop-up-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: got the answer here : [How to handle pop up in selenium webdriber using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403949/how-to-handle-pop-up-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score -1):

Please review again, this may be iframe, Please inspect with fire bug properly,and if page have iframe , then code with frame related property. If you feel again problem, please share the more information about code.

Comment: no it is not iframe. already check using firebug/firepath. when I inspect the pop up, it open another firebug/firepath. it is a fresh new html document / webpage.

Comment: then it should be manage by window handles properties.   

String obj= driver.getWindowHandle();
 
 driver.findElement(By.name("dob no")).sendKeys("12345");

Answer (score -1):

You can read more about iFrames and do something like this driver.switchtoiFrame. You will have to read its HTML to find it out if thats an iFrame, else if its a Pop-up then you need to switch to that Popup first

Comment: no it is not iframe. already check using firebug/firepath. when I inspect the pop up, it open another firebug/firepath. it is a fresh new html document / webpage