# Unable to click on object in Banking Netbanking site

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below Is the site page

[image: Banking Netbanking Page]

I'm trying to click on **Continue to Netbanking** button. But I am unable to do that. I have used `xpath` but its not working. Here is `xpath` which I've tried :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[6]/a/img")).click();
```

Steps:

1. Open URl http://www.hdfcbank.com
2. Click on Login button on website. New popup will get open.
3. Click on "Continue on Netbanking". THIS IS NOT WORKING

Here is code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("loginsubmit")).click();

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    Set<String> set = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();
    System.out.println(set.size());

    for( String windowTab : set){
        if(!windowTab.equalsIgnoreCase(MainWindow)){
            driver.switchTo().window(it.next());
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            String Wdinw2 = driver.getWindowHandle();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[6]/a/img")).click();

            break;
        }

    }
```

Console :

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[6]/a/img"}

Comment: I am just curious to know whey there is a **dot** before //*[@id='wrapper']

Comment: I guess you have to first move to another window, because when click on login button"Continue to NetBanking" button is showing inside another window. then try it with your xpath element.

Comment: did you handle the change to the pop up window? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403949/how-to-handle-pop-up-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: Assuming that you have permission to perform automation testing for this bank site. Financial websites especially banks are pretty paranoid about any automated access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use below code and let me know the result:

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);}

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("img[alt='continue']"))).click();
```

To switch back to main window (if you need):

```
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```

Comment: Agree with @andersson code, also if you want to click "contuie to NetBanking" button with xpath. you can use this way. `(By.xpath("//img[@src='/assets/images/netbanking_continue_red.gif']")).click();`