# Site Authentication webdriver codeception

Tags: selenium, webdriver, codeception

I am writing some automation tests, and the site my test needs to connect to requires a site authentication.

I'm not sure how to handle this pop-up in order to provide the username & password. If the dialogue box is closed then the site can not be reached .. e.g. unauthorised access.

I have tried using passing the credentials through the url, but that doesn't work. Any suggestions appreciated.

- acceptance.suite.yml

  `actor: AcceptanceTester
    modules:
    enabled:
      - WebDriver:
          browser: chrome
          url: "http://username:password@my.site.autenticated.url"
      - \Helper\Acceptance`

With this I get `Unable to parse URI: http://username:password@my.site.autenticated.url`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle Pop-up in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403949/how-to-handle-pop-up-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: Can you show how u are passing credentials in url .there you can missing some thing

Comment: @AnkurSingh I have modified my question to include what I have tried

Answer (score 1):

This  may help you :-

String Password = URLEncoder.encode("pass");

String UserName= URLEncoder.encode("UserName");

String url = String.format("http://%s:%s@xyz", UserName, Password);

In this %s is variable which pass to url in form of parameter .

You can refer this url also https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters

Comment: Thank you sir, completely forgot about the encoding, saved me hours

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
http://username:password@yourweburl/
```

example : -

```
driver.get("http://username:password@www.example.com/")
```

Comment: I have tried adding that into my acceptance suite : url config ..
`url: driver.get("http://username:password@my.authenticated.site.URL")`

Didn't work