# Pop Up Handling in Selenium for Keyword Driven Framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup

Is there a way to handle inconsistent PopUp/Alert in Selenium Framework apart from Try Catch block?

We have one Application which went through new enhancements this year and now there is new Forsee pop up which always appears in different pages. Basically I can't go back to each and every methods/Keywords in my Framework to implement Try Catch to handle it. Additionally if that appears in middle of keyword execution then I don't want it to go in Catch block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle Pop-up in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403949/how-to-handle-pop-up-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: No, this question is not related to my issue. I want to understand better approach to implement this handling for a Keyword Driven Framework where this pop is inconsistent and appears any time throughout the application

Comment: What is the information in these popups? Are they related to the workflow under test? Very hard to handle inconsistent popups other than asking the developers to shut them off. Maybe they have a kill switch using cookies etc in the framework.

Comment: It is just a Survey and as per logic it appears based on some no of visit.