# Not able to click on popup & close

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have opened this site https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-first-form-demo.html

as I open there is popup showing

How to go on that popup & click on close using selenium?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle Pop-up in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403949/how-to-handle-pop-up-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

Use below code. These are some chances that you are not using proper wait and XPath.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-first-form-demo.html");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='at-cv-lightbox-close']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='at-cv-lightbox-close']"));
    driver.quit();
```

Comment: Hi I tried below code pls check in screenshot but still got error
https://prnt.sc/ua1em0

Comment: XPath for user message highlighting two element, so you have to create unique xpath. Here I am using more than one attribute. XPath : //*[@id="user-message" and @class="form-control"]

Answer (score 1):

To click and close the *popup* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[title='Close']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@title='Close']"))).click();
  ```