# How do you detect if this popup is displayed

Tags: java, selenium, junit, automated-tests

I'm using Selenium with Junit framework while testing a website https://fitnesaveikals.lv/ I ran into a problem this popup shows up (the popup is a temporary thing the messaging could change and be replaced with marketing popups). Is there a way to check if this popup is there/visible? When manually testing the page the popup dialog shows up once but when testing while using lambdatest it shows up in every test time meaning the tests fail. [image: this is the popup that shows up]

Comment: And also i need to close it so that the test could continue.

Comment: Try to find it when opening your page, if it is there, select the close button and click it, if it is not displayed, juste resume your test.

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403949/how-to-handle-pop-up-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.className("mfp-close").click()`

Answer (score 0):

You should do try catch function to identify, no inbuild methods in selenium,

if it is there, it will close the pop up.

```
try{
   driver.findElement(By.className("mfp-close")).click();
}catch (Exception ex){
   system.out.println("pop is not displaying");
}
```